# What happens if the power method is applied with a starting vector $q=c_2 v_2+...+c_n v_n$ in the presence of roundoff errors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Supose $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is an eigenvector basis and $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>\ldots >|\lambda_n|>0$, so, my question is, if our starting vector $q \in span\{v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and in the presence of roundoff errors might happen $|\lambda_1|\approx |\lambda_2|$ and discussing with some friends, they said that in this case the power method would converge to $c_1 v_1$. I think this is not possible, because $span\{v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is an eigenspace thus is invariant A, and our subspace is finite dimensional so is closed, and the power method generate a sequence in $span\{v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ thus, must converge to a point in the closure, but unless $c_1=0$ it cannot converge to $c_1 v_1$, am I right? The power method should converge to $0$ if it converge at all. Is there any flaws here? 
Thank you.

Comment: With the presence of roundoff errors, it's very likely that we'll end up on $c_1 v_1$.  Note that while we can end up with a sequence converging to zero, this is an "unstable equilibrium", where as $c_1v_1$ is "stable".

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes sense if, for instance, you know $v_1$ and the considered matrix $A$ is normal; thus $span(v_2,\cdots,v_n)$ is $E$, the orthogonal of $v_1$. Then you choose a unitary  $u_0\in E$ and you consider the sequence $u_{n+1}=Au_n/||Au_n||$; note that this sequence cannot converge to $0$. Initially $u_n$ approaches the direction of $v_2$; secondly, because of roundoff errors, $u_n$ moves away from the direction of $v_2$ to the direction of $v_1$. You must stop the iteration when $(u_n.v_1)$ is no longer $\approx 0$.

Comment: I believe that if one would like to compute $v_2$ by the power method (assuming $A$ is normal and $v_1$ is known) then applying it to $A-\lambda v_1v_1^*$ ("moving" $\lambda_1$ to zero and making $\lambda_2$ the dominant eigenvalue) would work better instead of hoping that roundoff will not make too much "damage" to $u_n$.

Comment: @ Algebraic Pavel , I agree. Yet, if $A$ is not normal, then how to find $span(v_2,\dots,v_n)$ ?